# VBA Concatenate & Sum

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with writing a macro that can concatenate numbers on SHEET2 (that may look like this):

```
         A     B     C     D
 1       4     3     2     1
 2       5     6
 3       7     8     0
```

And come out with a sum on SHEET1 like this (4321+56+780=5157):

```
         A
 1     5157
```

I have no macro written so far, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: lol at least you're honest. Try multiplying the text by its place in the number. For example, 4(1000), 3(100), etc.

Comment: I don't think that really works - 4(1000) + 3(100) + 2(10) + 1(1) makes sense, but 5(1000) + 6(100) isn't what this person is looking for.

Comment: @KFichter lol obviously you test for how many places you need XD But answer below is far superior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know you can do this without a macro, right?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3&B1:B3&C1:C3&D1:D3)+0)
```

Comment: I know, but I have rows and rows of these numbers :( So I figured a macro would make it easier, but if anything, I can just write out an extremely long formula

Comment: The formula would't be any longer than what I have, you would just replace it with your ranges.

Comment: Oh you're right! I didn't look at it closely enough, sorry! Thank you so much for your help!! :)

Comment: Is there a way to select an undefined number of columns or rows? I don't think ranges can do this. The closest thing I know  is either scripting (my answer), or a range reaching until 65535 (2^16-1)

Comment: One last question! Is there any way to avoid the #VALUE error if some rows are blank?

Comment: This will work with ctrl+shift+enter

=SUMPRODUCT(IF(CONCATENATE(A1:A7,B1:B7,C1:C7,D1:D7)="","0",CONCATENATE(A1:A7,B1:B7,C1:C7,D1:D7))+0)

Comment: For rows you can just grab a very large range and use the formula I posted in comments. For undefined or too many columns VBA solution is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Use Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=SUM(CONCATENATE(A1:A3,B1:B3,C1:C3,D1:D3)*1)
```

Ignoring errors:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(CONCATENATE(B2:B4,C2:C4,D2:D4,E2:E4)*1,0))
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be exactly what you asked for. An Excel VBA script that concatenates all the values (forever) in each row in `Sheet2`, adds the row totals together, and displays them in `Sheet1`. I have tested it with your data set, and it works correctly.

```
Sub concatSum()
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim rowVal As String
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim colVal As String
    row = 1
    col = 1
    totalVal = 0
    rowVal = ""
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Do While Len(.Cells(row, 1).Value) > 0
            colVal = .Cells(row, col).Value
            Do While Len(colVal) > 0
                rowVal = rowVal & colVal
                col = col + 1
                colVal = .Cells(row, col).Value
            Loop
            col = 1
            row = row + 1
            totalVal = totalVal + rowVal
            rowVal = ""
        Loop
    End With
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = totalVal
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No *VBA* needed, use:

```
=VALUE(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1))+VALUE(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2))+VALUE(CONCATENATE(A3,B3,C3,D3))
```

and change the references to any sheet you like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub concadinate_sum()
Dim LstRow As Long
Dim LstCol As Long, c As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

LstRow = Sheets(2).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address).Count

For i = 1 To LstRow
    LstCol = Sheets(2).Range("A" & i, Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight).Address).Count
    For j = 0 To LstCol
       c = c & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Offset(0, j).Value
    Next j
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = CInt(c) + CInt(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value)
    c = ""
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is VBA solution

```
Sub AddThem()

Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

lr = sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
tot = 0
For i = 1 To lr

tot = tot + (Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 2) & Cells(i, 3) & Cells(i, 4)) + 0

Next i

Range("A1") = tot

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I guess that makes sense!